# How to get XML child hierachy in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

My XML structure looks like this.

```
<soap-env:Envolope xmlns:soap-env=.............>
   <soap-env:Header></<soap-env:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <n0:_-qte_-rfcReadStrucNodesResponse xmlns:n0=.................>
         <EsSysMessage>...</EsSysMessage>
         <EtNodes>
           <item>...</item>
           <item>...</item>
           <item>...</item>
           <item>...</item>
           <item>...</item>
           <item>...</item>
...
```

I'd like to get list of item under EtNodes. I tried getElementsByName("EtNodes") but it doesn't work.

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use *[getElementsByTagName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp)*, so something like this:

```
var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("EtNodes")[0].childNodes;
```

Check out this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp) from w3schools.